# Display a message if email is Verified permanently on user profile page, Laravel 10

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel and on learning stage at the moment.

My question is;
I'm trying to display 'your email is verified' after users verify their emails. Under profile page, I want the message to be displayed all the time, so users can see it is verified. I'm using jetstream

```
   @if (Laravel\Fortify\Features::enabled(Laravel\Fortify\Features::emailVerification()) && ! $this->user->hasVerifiedEmail())
            <p class="text-sm mt-2">
                {{ __('Your email address is unverified.') }}
```

I have attached a screenshot as well.  Can anyone the pro-experts can have a moment to help me with this simple code?

Thanks in advance.
[Screenshot of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf49g.png)

I have tried adding into update-profile-information-form.blade.php  but I'm getting errors, I assume I need an expert advice.

Comment: Not sure where the problem is, you already have the opposite condition in the code you posted. Does removing `!` from `! $this->user->hasVerifiedEmail()` not solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured out by writing the following code after checking the database
for the email verified, and worked like a charm, simple and yet powerful.

I hope it also helps to others who wants to do same.

```
   @if(Auth::user()->email_verified_at != null)
    verified 
    @else
      Not verified
  @endif
```

Just add your own styling to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
     @if (auth()->user()->email_verified)
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            Your email is verified permanently.
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
            Your email is not yet verified.
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: Thank you Usama for answering. + Voted :)